# swagger codegen add @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) annotation to a single field

Tags: spring, swagger-codegen, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm currently using swagger codegen using yml to generate my models However I have one field, that is a `List<Object>` that needs to have the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`. I can see the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` in `POJO.mustache` but not in `model.mustache`. Does anyone know what to add in the yaml file or anywhere else so that field gets generated with that annotation? Thanks. I'm using spring-java language with gradle. I need this to be generated during build. so minimal changes are preferred.

Comment: Till you find a way to add the Jackson annotation, you can use a work around where you can use your own model.  `https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#bringing-your-own-models` This is a workaround and not the answer you are seeking, hence I'm commenting it here.

Comment: Thanks for Help.
Work Around worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the readme on their git, Swagger Codegen mention ways to do this:

> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md

since you're using gradle:

We can use a custom template for the code generation as follows:

```
// build.gradle
swaggerSources {
  inputFile = file('{name of your file}.yaml')
  xyz {
    language = 'spring'
    // template directory path
    templateDir = file('templates/{name of your custom directory}')
  }
}
```

inside `templates/{name of your custom directory}`, you can store your custom mustache files, as in your case, all you have to do is download the required spring templates from [git](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache) (e.g. this link is for pojo.mustache)
and add in the required changes to the template, along with the project and libraries folder. Run gradle build and it should generate.

There is a much simpler workaround however, where you can just use your own pojo class and add this in your existing `config.json` and remove the earlier entry for that model in your yaml file (of course):

```
  "importMappings" : {
      "{replace with className}": "{replace with packageName}.{replace with className}"
  }
```

Hope this helps.